# Добавление в ссылку атрибута onclick

Tags: php, javascript, html

Нужно подтверждение удаления ссылки на сайте.

Код самой кнопки-ссылки:

```
function wpfp_remove_favorite_link($post_id) {
    if (wpfp_is_user_can_edit()) {
        $wpfp_options = wpfp_get_options();
        $class = 'wpfp-link remove-parent';
        /*$link = "<a id='rem_$post_id' class='$class' href='?wpfpaction=remove&amp;page=1&amp;postid=". $post_id ."' title='".wpfp_get_option('rem')."' rel='nofollow'>".wpfp_get_option('rem')."</a>";*/
        $link = "<a id='rem_$post_id' class='$class' href='?wpfpaction=remove&amp;page=1&amp;postid=". $post_id ."' title='Удалить' rel='nofollow'>".wpfp_get_option('rem')."</a>";
        $link = apply_filters( 'wpfp_remove_favorite_link', $link );
        echo $link;
    }
}
```

Как я понимаю, достаточно приставить к ней вот это:

```
language='javascript' onclick="return confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить это?')"
```

Вопрос: как это интегрировать в мою функцию?

Comment: Возможно, сейчас кто-нибудь предложит решение с экранированием скобок, но вы всё же задумайтесь: не кажется ли вам дикая мешанина из PHP, HTML и JS плохим стилем программирования?

Comment: кажется. изначально я нашла сторонний скрипт и добавила кнопкоссылке класс, по которому должен был сработать скрипт. но не сработало ничего. случайно нашла это. спросила здесь. вдруг кто предложит еще какое то решение.

Comment: А сторонний скрипт точно был подключен?

Comment: @ДмитрийЗаварзин, ну да. я просто вставила его для быстроты прямо на странице. другие, по крайней мере, так работали в том числе.

Comment: @AnnaFrank возможно, вас всё уже устроит решение с помощью подключаемого JS-скрипта, в котором будут обрабатываться клики? Например,  всех `<a>` с указанным классом.

Comment: @Regent возможно. надо поискать.

Comment: @AnnaFrank да зачем искать - я могу написать его за несколько минут. А с jQuery было бы ещё быстрее. Но важны два момента: 1. Вас должно устраивать такое решение. 2. Нужен итоговый (отображаемый в браузере) HTML-код ссылки, без всякого PHP-кода в ней.

Comment: @Regent неожиданно. чудно.
1) окау
2) html <a id="rem_447" class="wpfp-link remove-parent" href="?wpfpaction=remove&amp;page=1&amp;postid=447" title="Удалить" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с обработкой ссылок с классом `remove-parent`.

- Дожидаемся загрузки документа.
- Выбираем все элементы с классом `remove-parent`.
- Для каждого из этих элементов добавляем обработчик события `click`.
- В обработчике события спрашиваем у пользователя подтверждения. Если пользователь отказался, запрещаем действия по умолчанию (переход по ссылке).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDomReady);

function onDomReady() {
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-parent');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (!confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить это?')) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

```html
<a id="rem_447" class="wpfp-link remove-parent" href="?wpfpaction=remove&amp;page=1&amp;postid=447" title="Удалить" rel="nofollow">Ссылка</a>
```